# Ajax jsf 2 sort datatable based on select list item selection (on button click)

Tags: ajax, jsf

So I want to ajax up a data table to change and be filtered based on which state is selected in the drop down. I have the following:

```
        <p>Choose State to Filter By:</p> 

                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{productListingBean.choosenState}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="All" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{productListingBean.stateList}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <h:commandButton value="Sort">
                    <f:ajax event="action" render="myTable" />
                </h:commandButton>
```

and

```
<h:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{productListingBean.getAllProducts()}" var="product" styleClass="hovertable">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    ID
                </f:facet> ...
```

my product bean is request scoped and I save the selection from the selectOnmenu in the Choosen state variable and getAllProducts() method handles the filtering.

What am I missing, this does not work?

Comment: are both components inside the same form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues seems to be that this needs to be surrounded in a  tag.